GitHub CoPilot in Visual Studio: explicitly request a completion
I use copilot in visual studio with C# projects. As far as I understand it mostly requests a completion after you click enter, i.e. on a new line. This can be traced in Output window of Visual Studio after switching it to GitHub Copilot. Requests are shown there. But if I make changes in the middle of a line it mostly doesn't request any suggestion. I say mostly, because sometimes it still does, what triggers it is unclear for me.
Now here there is a scenario: I have an old project where all class variables are prefixed with unnecessary "this." Like
int i = this._myCounter;

I'd like to remove these prefixes, these are tens in not hundreds per file. I start doing it manually and sometimes, very rarely, and I don't know what triggers it, CoPilot catches the idea and offers to delete one after another by clicking tab. But it doesn't do it in every file and even in one file/class it sometimes thinks it is done while there are still plenty left. In the majority of cases it doesn't even ask a server, which, again, can be traced in the output window.
So, is there a way (a hotkey?) to explicitly request a code suggestion in Visual Studio? Then I can point it to "this." part and it will probably guess what's needed.
